# Perfect forwarding return type of a template class member function

Tags: c++, gcc, auto, perfect-forwarding, c++-concepts

Consider [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ujjXsP) code:

```
int TEN = 10;

template < typename >
struct XX
{
    //static auto&& ban(auto&&...) // FAILS!?
    template < typename... Args > static auto&& ban(Args&&...)
    { return TEN; }
};

int main()
{
    XX<void>::ban();
    return 0;
}
```

The declaration of `ban(auto&&...)` fails with

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'auto&&' from expression of type 'int'
```

when compiling with `gcc-8.3 -std=c++17 -fconcepts`.

So, is this a bug in the implementation of GCC?

Note that it passes when class `XX` is not a template.

Comment: Try `-std=c++2a`, though you mind need a newer GCC for that to work still

Comment: @StoryTeller Fails as well.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm `error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'auto&&' from expression of type 'int'`

Comment: Compiles for me with g++ 8.3.0 (with or without `-fconcepts`)

Comment: Well then, either as an extension or as a standard feature, seems GCC doesn't support it correctly still.

Comment: @TobySpeight Are you sure? The live example at `godbolt` shows that it doesn't.

Comment: @Vahagn - The live example builds fine. You may have linked to the wrong version when (un)commenting stuff.

Comment: @Vahagn, yes, I copy-pasted from the question and compiled it without any errors.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69448

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it look like a compiler bug.

A simple workaround would be to use trailing return type:

```
static auto ban(auto&&...) -> auto&& // strangely work
{ return TEN; }
```

Also, note that this syntax is not yet fully supported by GCC. The concept terse template syntax should allow this:

```
template<typename>
concept /* bool */ test = true;

auto func(test auto) -> void {}
```

And don't quite work yet with GCC concepts implementation.